# Using $\ln x<(x^\epsilon-1)/\epsilon$ for $x>1$ and $\epsilon>0$, and the squeeze theorem, show that $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}(\ln x)/x^\epsilon=0$

Tags: real-analysis, asymptotics

A question from *Introduction to analysis* by Arthur Mattuck:

> Given $\epsilon \gt 0$, $\ln x \lt \frac {(x^\epsilon - 1)} {\epsilon}$, for $x \gt 1$. Deduce that $\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{\ln x}{x^\epsilon}=0$ for any $\epsilon \gt 0$ using the squeeze theorem.

Now I know how to prove the first inequality by integration, but how to get the second limit by using Squeeze Theorem? $$\frac{\ln x}{x^\epsilon} \lt \frac{(x^\epsilon - 1)}{\epsilon x^\epsilon}=\frac{1}{\epsilon}(1-\frac{1}{x^\epsilon})$$
The limit of $\frac{1}{\epsilon}(1-\frac{1}{x^\epsilon})$ is $\frac{1}{\epsilon}$ as $x$ tends to $\infty$, not $0$.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I find it quite amusing that a simple theorem is proved in a very complicated fashion: $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\ln x}{x^\varepsilon}=0$ if and only if $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\varepsilon\ln x}{x^\varepsilon}=0$ if and only if $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\ln(x^\varepsilon)}{x^\varepsilon}=0$ if and only if $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\ln x}{x}=0$. Now, for the last one, consider it is the same, up to multiplication by a constant, as $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\ln x}{x^2}$ and use $\ln x<1+x$.

Comment: @egreg Thanks! Because I have not learned $\ln x \lt 1+x$, and the question demands using of Squeeze Theorem.

Comment: "Now I know how to prove the first inequality by integration, but how to get the second limit by using Squeeze Theorem?" Interestingly, it seems nobody addressed the second part of the phrase, which is actually the question asked. A.: **Use the inequality for $\epsilon/2$**, thus, $$\log x\leqslant(2/\epsilon)(x^{\epsilon/2}-1)$$ which implies $$(\log x)/x^\epsilon\leqslant(2/\epsilon)(x^{\epsilon/2}-1)/x^\epsilon=(2/\epsilon)(1-x^{-\epsilon/2})x^{-\epsilon/2}\to(2/\epsilon)(1-0)\cdot0=0$$

Comment: @Did Thanks! two $\epsilon$ can be different!

Comment: Indeed, this is a way to describe the trick used here.

Answer (score 0):

hint.
$$\ln x=\int_1^x\frac{1}{t}\,dt<\int_1^x\frac{t^\varepsilon}{t}\,dt=\frac{x^\varepsilon-1}{\varepsilon}$$

Comment: Thanks! That helped a lot. But I still don't know how to solve the second question.

Comment: $\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{\ln x}{x^\epsilon} \leq \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{x^\epsilon - 1}{\epsilon x^{\epsilon}}$

Comment: @Hongyan for all $x$ as $x\to\infty$, let $\varepsilon>x$.

Comment: @maryam that doesn't make sense to me, $x$ is tending to infinity, $\epsilon$ is fixed

Comment: @ConnorHarris but $\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac {x^\epsilon -1}{\epsilon x^\epsilon} = \frac {1}{\epsilon}$, not $0$.

Comment: @qbert yes, $\epsilon$ is fixed. I don't know how Squeeze Theorem is used  here.